# Invoke BitLocker Unlock GUI from a script

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, shell-script, bitlocker

In a script, I need a way for a user to unlock a BitLocker encrypted volume.

Currently, the user types the password in PowerShell console window (`$key = Read-Host 'BitLocker Password for $($path)' -AsSecureString`) and then BitLocker volume is being unlocked with `Unlock-Bitlocker` cmdlet.

What I would like, is a 'more natural' standard GUI prompt for unlocking the volume, like this one:

[image: Unlock BitLocker GUI prompt]

Is there a way to invoke this GUI from a `.cmd`/`.ps1` script?
I'm thinking of something like:

- starting an executable, i.e. `some-bitlocker-gui.exe /unlock C:\SomeSecurePath /askuserforpassword`
- PowerShell cmdlet
- calling a function in some DLL

But any way of showing that native GUI will suit.

**One important note:** this should work not only for drive letters (like `D:`), but **for [volumes mounted as NTFS folders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_volume_mount_point) as well** (like `C:\SomeSecurePath`, as seen in the screenshot):

[image: volume mounted as NTFS folder]

Comment: You can use bdeunlock to display the password prompt like in the Windows Explorer, but I don't know whether this also works for mount points. Example `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "$env:windir\System32\bdeunlock.exe" -ArgumentList 'D:'` or simply in batch `bdeunlock.exe F:`

Comment: @pwnosh, thanks! Unfortunately, `bdeunlock C:\SomeSecurePath` displays `0x8007005` error. However, when the drive is being unlocked from within Control Panel (`control /name Microsoft.BitLockerDriveEncryption`), it seems that `bdeunlock.exe` is still being called (at least it appears in task manager).  Looks like a good point to start with.

Comment: @pwnosh, I got it! The required command line looks like `bdeunlock \\?\Volume{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000}\ `. The volume identifier could be obtained with `$(Get-BitLockerVolume)[1].MountPoint` PowerShell command, where `1` is a volume number (starting with zero). I suggest you post your comment as an answer (with this little addition), and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required command is

```
bdeunlock \\?\Volume{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000}\
```

where `{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000}` is volume identifier of the required BitLocker volume.

The volume identifier can be obtained with

```
$(Get-BitLockerVolume)[1].MountPoint
```

PowerShell command, where `1` is a volume number (starting with zero).

**CREDIT:** [@swbbl](https://superuser.com/users/1248556/), as [suggested in this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1660816/invoke-bitlocker-unlock-gui-from-a-script#comment2544950_1660816).

Answer (score -1):

Nope; that modal dialog is programmed in the BitLocker management code.

Outside of writing your own, you can write your code and send it to Show-Command for a GUI, for a user to input stuff.

A folder/network share, is not a drive, regardless of the drive mapping on a user's machine. It's just a pointer.

Bitlocker is the full drive or noting. BitLocker means FDE (full drive encryption) for a reason. Access to a BL drive is all or nothing. BitLocker by design, if for protection against off-line attacks. Once the BitLocker drive is spun up, everyone that can see it has access to it. You cannot BitLocker a drive (mapped) to a user.

You can connect to a drive as an iSCI instead of SMB if it’s supported by your storage server. Of course, BitLocker use is native using iSCI drives.

Alternatively, consider, create a Virtual Disk Drive file with BitLocker and store that on an SMB network drive. Shared folder encryption, you need other tools.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Just to be clear: There are no servers etc, both `C:` and `C:\SomeSecurePath` are two separate NTFS partitions on a locally installed SSD.. The first `C:` partition is NTFS (unencrypted), and the second one is NTFS BitLocker-encrypted. But, instead of the usual way of assigning `D:` to that second partition, it is made available as `C:\SomeSecurePath` via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_volume_mount_point